# Cant fix Python error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python

My source code

```
def display_inventory(inventory):
    print("Itme list")
    item_total = 0
    for k,v in inventory.items():
        print(str(k) + str(v))
        item_total = item_total + v.get(k,0)
    print("The total number of items:" + str(item_total))

stuff = {'rope':1, 'torch':6, 'coin':42, 'Shuriken':1, 'arrow':12}
display_inventory(stuff)
```

error message

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Could you please tell me how I can fix this error? I'd appreciate if you could also explain why this doesn't work.

thank you in advance

Comment: It makes sense that int has no attribute get. What do you think get should even do here?

Comment: `for k, v in dict.items()`. Thus `v` takes on the value of the element having `k` as key. Apparently, this element is an int, thus you can not apply the method get to an integer. get can be applied to a dict, e.g. to inventory. thus the 2 correct lines are `item_total + v` OR `item_total +inventory.get(k)`

Answer (score 1):

1. `get` should be called on the dictionary (i.e. `inventory`).
2. There is no need to call `get` because `v = inventory[k]` in the loop.
3. You do not need to have a default in case `k` does not exist because `for k,v in inventory.items()` only loops through existing items.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply write the following:

```py
def display_inventory(inventory):
    print("Itme list")
    item_total = 0
    for k,v in inventory.items():
        print(str(k) + str(v))
        item_total = item_total + v  # <<< CHANGE HERE
    print("The total number of items:" + str(item_total))

stuff = {'rope':1, 'torch':6, 'coin':42, 'Shuriken':1, 'arrow':12}
display_inventory(stuff)
```

Because in this cause the value `v` is the number corresponding to the product which you want to add up. There is no need to make any further dictionary lookups using `get()` because you already have the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

In your dictionary, `v` is an integer. Everything in the dictionary is fetched in `inventory.items()`.And you are trying to fetch something from an intege. Hence it shows an error. The solution is simply change to `v`

```
def display_inventory(inventory: dict):
    print("Item list")
    item_total = 0
    for k,v in inventory.items():
        print(str(k) + str(v))
        item_total = item_total + v #=== Here
    print("The total number of items:" + str(item_total))

stuff = {'rope':1, 'torch':6, 'coin':42, 'Shuriken':1, 'arrow':12}
display_inventory(stuff)
```

And the output:

```
rope1
torch6
coin42
Shuriken1
arrow12
The total number of items:62
```

Comment: Welcome @Eric .

Comment: I dont understand why this question is -2, need 1 more person to help neutralise the downvote

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in the line with `v.get(k,0)`. The syntax for `.get()` function is

`<dict>.get(<key>, <default value if key not found>` and outputs a value in the dictionary,

whereas the usual `<dict>[<key>]` method would throw an error if the key is not present.

Specific to your code when iterating through the key-value pair `for k,v in inventory.items():`, the key is guaranteed to be present.

And since you are already iterating through the values in the dictionary, so you could simply use

`item_total += v`.

Additional feedback on `print(str(k) + str(v))`, you could try the following:

1. Use `+` notation `print(str(k) + ' ' + str(v))` which allows *only* `string`
2. Or use `,` notation `print(k, v)` which allows a mix of `string` and `list`
3. Use `,` notation in `print("The total number of items:", item_total)`

Output

```
rope 1
torch 6
coin 42
Shuriken 1
arrow 12
The total number of items: 62
```

By the way there is a typo in `print("Itme list")`.

Cheers!